# How can I have OSS project login to fb without creating a page or an app with my account?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

The recommended way by fb is to get a token but the simple act of getting this token ties my personal account and an app created with it to my credentials. Is there a way for OSS projects to get a temporary or permanent token for their API login access without this connection back on a specific account?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: If it's true, then Web3 has won my interest then.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different tokens: App Token, User Token, Page Token. Only the App Token is not bound to a user, but you cannot do much with it.

Quite old, but still: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/